# How to get an instance of android.app.UiAutomation

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-uiautomator

I am testing some new features of Android 5.0, and now is the round of the `UiAutomator` and the new method implemented. I've tried to search for an example/guide, then I've tried to get an instance of UiAutomator by

```
getSystemService()
```

but that was not helpful. My goal is to use [`executeShellCommands(String str)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand%28java.lang.String%29).

Has anyone already implemented?

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question so that it makes good sense of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Yes sure.. Scuse me for the incorrect phrase form..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to clarify, the UiAutomation class is not part of UiAutomator (although they have similar names).

You can obtain a UiAutomation instance by calling
[Instrumentation#getUiAutomation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html#getUiAutomation()). This only works if you're running an Instrumentation-based test.

If this is part of a shell-based UiAutomator test, then you can use [Runtime#exec()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) to execute a shell command.